# Aligning text using CSS in a <ul> <li>

Tags: html, css

Here is my CSS:

```
ul.list-ok {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}

ul.list-ok li {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    height: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
}

.fa-angle-right:before {
  content: "\f105";
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<ul class="list-ok" style="margin-top: 25px !important;display:inline-block;">
<li style="height: initial;"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Streamlined processes saving you time and money. This is a very long bullet point that needs to wrap and wrap and wrap so that a very long paragraph lines up properly.</li>
<li style="height: initial;"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>A+ rated with the BBB</li>
</ul>
```

Here is my output:

[image: Picture of the output of my CSS and HTMK]

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/wbokm4dL/2/) is my fiddle.

Here is my issue ;)

I would like the the word 'and' to wrap properly and line up with the start of the other text, I was able to achieve that with using other list-styles but the client wants to use this method.  I have searched google and tried a number of different techniques to align the text and also tried enclosing my text in `<p>` and other elements in an effort to achieve my desired output.  I am at a loss and seem to be getting further away from the answer the more tutorials I follow and links I find on google. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

I have used the attribute `display:inline-block;` but it cuts the text off on a mobile device so this is not an option, i need the text to wrap properly.  In an effort to make the question more simple I cut out several bullet points that are quite long

This is what I would like the finished product to look like, but using my custom bullet point created by the `fa-angle-right` class:

[image: ideal outcome]

Answer (score 1):

Try `white-space:nowrap` [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akshay7/wbokm4dL/1/)

```css
ul.list-ok {
    list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
   
}

ul.list-ok li {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    height: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
    white-space:nowrap;
 
}

.fa-angle-right:before {
  content: "\f105";
  
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-ok" style="margin-top: 25px !important;display:inline-block;">
    
<li style="height: initial;"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Streamlined processes saving you time and money</li>
<li style="height: initial;"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>A+ rated with the BBB</li>
    
</ul>
```

Comment: I should have mentioned this, but that is one of the first things I tried, but as this is being displayed on a mobile device it just cuts it off. I will edit my question to better reflect this.  I need the text to wrap properly.

Comment: @Dylan So how would you like it to be ?

Comment: @Dylan You can try giving it a specified width https://jsfiddle.net/akshay7/wbokm4dL/3/

Comment: I would like it to look like this, as far as the text alignment goes. http://i.gyazo.com/457331ddcb937a5f781888710e7cab83.png

Comment: But this would not transition well between big screen monitors and tiny Samsung Galaxy S2 mobile phones, right?  I need this to be "responsive."

Comment: @Dylan Did you try `text-align:justify` ?

Comment: I did yes, this is what it does with or without that attribute. http://i.gyazo.com/8ed61f3e8efc5455e83f2ebd8060d404.png

Comment: @Dylan With that i would suggest using a width and try percentage , `vw`  or `media` to solve the responsive issue

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the li text in '`<\span><\/span>`' tag and style it with as per your need.
try to fix the `min-width` of the `<\span><\/span>` so that it will not distorted in smaller screens.

Comment: All of the different attributes that I can apply to the span move the entire line of text below the bullet point as seen here.  http://gyazo.com/388e09ac1b440e1517b2e341275777b6